# TypeError when running numpy select

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to run code that takes in a csv and returns multiple csv simultaneously based on matching certain string values in the url through the luigi package.

Code:

```
class wrapper(luigi.WrapperTask):
        file = '/Users/emmanuels/Desktop/cleanattribution.csv'
        conditions  = [(file["properties_path"].str.contains('blog|article|page/2|page/3|pulse-2019') ==  True)|
                       (file["context_page_title"].str.contains('blog|Blog') == True),
                       (file["properties_path"].str.contains('credit|index.html|announce|translate_url|search|welcome|card-machines|static|point-of-sale-app|team|transaction|y-store|store|about|yoco-tap|faq|control|integrations|connect-reader|fitness|accessories|v3|vend|top-5|press|stories|xero|where-to-buy|tabletp|info|reseller|retail|v2|card|affiliates|vwo|small-business-profile|translate_c') == True)|
                       (file["properties_path"] == '/i')|
                       (file["properties_url"] == 'https://www.yoco.co.za/za/'),
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('signup|sign-up|create-account|continue|checkout|merchant-agreement|restart|terms|pickup|pick-up') == True,
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('complete') == True,
                       (file["properties_path"] == '/da/') | 
                       (file['properties_path'] == '/') | 
                       (file['properties_path'].str.contains('hair') == True)|
                       (file['properties_path'] == '/da'),
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('promo|iHeartMarket|BrownSense|growth-awards|SolBeerSouthAfrica|2ov|festival-of-beer|Pretoria|tourism|payday||brownsense|iheartmarket|plan-my-wedding|hello-pretty|readyforseason|matchmakers|priceless|optimizely|awethu|flash-sale|2017|pretoriaeast|digi') == True,
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('capital') == True,
                       (file["properties_path"].str.contains('justst|just|Just-Start|growth') == True)|
                       (file["context_page_title"].str.contains('Just Start') == True),
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('careers')== True,
                       (file["properties_path"].str.contains('contact|call-me-back|demos|demo') == True)|
                       (file["context_page_title"].str.contains('Contact')==True),
                       (file["context_page_title"].str.contains('portal') == True)|
                       (file["properties_url"].str.contains('portal') == True)|
                       (file["properties_path"].str.contains('portal|history|email-notifications|point-of-sale|invoices|account|settlements|hardware|products|lets-grow|reports|business/details') == True),
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('for-the-sales|forthe') == True,
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('developers|sdk') == True,
                       (file["context_page_title"] == 'Not Found')|
                       (file["properties_path"].str.contains('404|page-data.json|not-found') == True)|
                       (file["context_page_title"] == 'Page not found')|
                       (file["properties_path"].str.contains('Get%20Yo') == True),
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('abtasty') == True,
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('401') == True,
                       file["properties_path"].str.contains('df') == True,
                       (file["context_page_title"].str.contains('Testing|Generating preview|moove_landing') == True)|
                       (file["properties_path"].str.contains('moove_landing') == True),
                       (file["properties_path"].str.contains('Users|storage|blank|conversion-test|temp|jiuze|api/v1|object%20|NaN|EMBROIDERY') == True)|
                       file["properties_search"].str.contains('elementor-preview') == True]
        choices = [ "blog","info_pages","signup","completed","home_page","promo_pages","ds-capital","just-start","careers_page","contact","portal","for_the_sales","developers","404","abtasty","401-protected page","Yogoals","Testing","Other"]
        file["page_type"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)
        actions = list(set(file["page_type"]))
        def requires(self):
                task_list = []
                for current_task in actions:
                        task_list = task_list.append(data_filter(task=current_task))
                return task_list
        def run(self):
                print ('Wrapper has ended')
                pd.DataFrame().to_csv('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/GitHub/datawranglerwrapper.csv') #will continue running if we don't add this here- we know everything before has been run
        def output(self):
                return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/GitHub/datawranglerwrapper.csv') #indicator of success, if successful won't run again
if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run(wrapper(workers=2))
```

The problem is that when I run my code on terminal, I keep encountering this error message:

```
  File "cleancopy.py", line 19, in wrapper
    conditions  = [(file["properties_path"].str.contains('blog|article|page/2|page/3|pulse-2019') ==  True)|
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 0):

'file' is of string type. Use integer values as indices and not variables.